# Android: how to use selector?

Tags: android, selector

I have a problem of using selector that it does not work as what I expect. I wanna click on it then it gives me reaction and I select it(By long click but I probably do it through programmatic way) then it gives me another reaction. However, it reacts nothing in result....

reaction part:

```
 <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="10"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_weight="9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_row">
                        <TextView 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/grey"
                            android:text="@string/tel"/>
                        <TextView 
                            android:id="@+id/telText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/blank"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:id="@+id/tel_call"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_call"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_left"/>                    
                </TableRow>
```

selector_row.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/semitransparent_grey"></item>
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/semitransparent_blue"></item>
    <item 
        android:drawable="@color/transparent"></item>
    </selector>
```

Comment: You miss a "normal" state

Comment: but I will do nothing in normal state

Comment: You MUST have a relaxed state. So it will return to THAT graphic, when not pressed/focused

Comment: how to set its normal state???I will not put any color on normal state. Can you post certain code??thx

Comment: I tried to put the selector to textview but when i press the text, it also reacts nothing

Answer (score 1):

Create an XML file and place it in the drawable folder. Open it and write the following code:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item 
        android:drawable="YOUR IMAGE OR COLOR"

         android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="YOUR IMAGE OR COLOR"

          android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="YOUR IMAGE OR COLOR"

           android:state_focused="true"/>

</selector>
```

Then in your main XML file, place `android:background="@drawable/selector.xml"`

Comment: android:state_normal<- no such option :O

Comment: I am just making a custom selector

Comment: `place it in the drawable-hdpi folder` It's **not the right place**. Put it in the `/res/drawable` folder, instead - since it's common to all screen densities.

Comment: No, it won't. but it's formally not correct. And it's a bad habit to put things in random places, just because `it doesn't make any change`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all brothers trying hard to answer me. I have got the answer....just simply by setting android:clickable="true" at LinearLayout. Ha, it's silly.....

I remember dude who provide relating information but I ignored... sorry to him.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting? A reaction only when it's clicked?

Try removing removing:

```
android:state_selected="true"
```

**Edit:**
This should be your selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable"></item>

</selector>
```

What is the behaviour that you are experiencing?

**Edit:**

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_weight="9"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/selector_row"
     android:duplicateParentState=true>
```

I don't know if it actually solves the problem

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another color or background over your root layout? Can you post the whole xml layout resource?

Comment: So can you tell me what is the wrong behaviour that you are experiencing?

Comment: I click it, no response

Comment: Can you try adding duplicateParentState to true in the xml?

Comment: A layout property like android:layout_width

Comment: That's really strange. Can you post the part of the code where the layout is used?

Comment: I have found the answer by setting clickable, I thought it was automatically set but actually it was not. By the way, Thank you:)