# Using 9-patch in android app

Tags: android, button, android-studio, nine-patch

I've created my 9-patch images for my android buttons and have looked for (what would hardly be) tutorials on how to use them in the app (I'm using Android Studio btw), and I haven't been able to locate any decent explanation on how to do just that.  I was able to find one that I thought was straight forward, but it didn't work.  So scratching that, can anyone link me to, or simply explain how to use the 9-patch files (normal, focused, pressed, disabled)?

EDIT: To be clear.  I've created my 4 images (for the 4 different states of the button), as I said.  I'm not sure what to do to use those images in my app as buttons. What steps do I take to use the images?

ACTIVITY.XML

```
<button
   android:style="@drawable/button_default"/>
```

STYLES.XML

```
<style name="button_default">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/buttons</item>
</style>
```

BUTTONS.XML

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/default_disabled"
        android:state_enabled="false"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/default_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_focused"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_normal"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_focused="false"/>

</selector>
```

...and my drawables are in "drawable-hdpi".  Named "default_disabled.9.png", "default_focused.9.png", "default_normal.9.png", "default_pressed.9.png".

Where'd I go wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and what is your progress so far? can you post any screenshot or your nine-patch image?

Comment: When you create a 9Patch image (which is small in size VECTOR image), you get flexibility to change: stretch that image and it won't be pixelated (as it's a vector). You can make a 9Patch [here](http://draw9patch.com/#url=http://draw9patch.com/image/btn.png&top[]=25&top[]=50&right[]=25&right[]=50&bottom[]=25&bottom[]=50&left[]=25&left[]=50).  [More about it](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html). Rest, it's used like a normal image.

Comment: **2nd part** (normal, focused, pressed, disabled):: Make 3 images of same size with same patches and then make a [selector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905937/3531756) and add those images in that.

Comment: I edited my post to hopefully clarify for those that couldn't understand what I already wrote.

Comment: @Tushar, I clearly stated that I have made the images.  My issue is that I haven't been able to locate a good "how-to" on using the images in the app.  What code do I need to replace a button with an image, and have that button utilize all 4 states (normal, disabled, focused, pressed)?

Comment: @lilgodwin `My issue is that I haven't been able to locate a good "how-to" on using the images in the app`: I have explained each part of the question. It's funny you didn't read the whole thing.

Comment: Haha, if you say so.  What little was comprehensible ended up being very vague and not helpful.

Comment: `android:state_enabled="true"` is not really required.

Answer (score 2):

There are three steps to this.  Here's a real example from one of my apps.

`res/drawable/button_red.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_red_normal" />

    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_red_pressed" />

    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" />
</selector>
```

Each of the drawables (e.g., `@drawable/button_red_normal`) is a 9-patch with different versions for each resolution (e.g., `res/drawable-hdpi/button_red_normal.9.png`)

In `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="button_common">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="button_red" parent="@style/button_common">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_red</item>
</style>
```

I split this into a parent and child style because I have more than one color of button in the app.  They differ only in their background drawable.

Finally, add this to the XML for your button:

```
style="@style/button_red"
```

Comment: Thank you!  I haven't tried it yet, but I'm going to.  I just appreciate that it looks like someone actually READ the post and responded to the question.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Question:  Are the different versions necessary for the resolutions? (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi)  It just seems like a lot to have 16 images for 1 button (4 states X 4 resolutions).

Comment: @lilgodwin 9patch images are too small in size so it won't matter.

Comment: Different resolutions are not strictly necessary.  If you don't provide them, Android will pick the closest size available and scale it on the fly, which might look bad or it might look just fine.

Comment: Alright, so I think I'm close to getting it, but one thing seems to be confusing me.  Your style says `@drawable/button_red` and I'm not sure what that's in reference to?  It looks like it's referencing the "button_red" within "button_red_normal" and "button_red_pressed", but that would leave out "button_default".  My files are named "default_disabled.9.png", "default_focused.9.png", "default_normal.9.png", "default_pressed.9.png".  And they're located in drawable-hdpi, and the values XML is "buttons.xml".  But `@drawable/default` nor `@drawable/button` works.  (I get red squiggly line error)

Comment: @lilgodwin The button XML in the activity layout references the style XML, which references the drawable XML, which references the images (`button_red_normal`, `button_red_pressed`, etc.)

Comment: Alright, I edited my main post again to include (I believe) everything relevant.  Why am I still getting a red underline on the styles background (@drawable)?  I've tried /buttons, /default, etc.

Comment: @lilgodwin  Are the file names capitalized the way you capitalized them in your question?  Is buttons.xml in res/drawable?

Comment: @lilgodwin Also, just to be clear, that isn't my entire styles.xml.  That's just what I added to the default stuff that was in there already.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know that buttons.xml was supposed to be in drawable/.  I created a new xml and it automatically put it in 'values'. I put it in drawable/ and it cleared up the red underline.  But now when I try to compile it says Error:(12) No resource identifier found for attribute 'style' in package 'android'
Error:(21, 32) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@drawable/button_default').

Comment: Oh, and my files aren't capitalized.

Comment: Update:  I had to remove the `android:` I put before `style="@drawable/buttons"`.  I goofed.  So, now I can compile, but now that one button that I added the new style to is default gray, and it isn't showing any of my 9-patch images in any of its states.  It's just a plain button.

Comment: Well, I went the cheap route (just to see if it'd work) and I copied your code into my file and just replaced the image names.  It works.  And I have no idea why.  I showed you what I did, and I thought it was verbatim what you told me to do.  It seems I messed up somewhere, I'm assuming it was some confusion with the names and what references what.  I do appreciate it.  If you get the chance to look at my revised post and maybe you can tell me what I did do wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. It's not necessary, but I would feel much better knowing how I messed up.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Nine path image is used for fixing an image part in the app. simply it over comes the scratching problems.

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Use this link for nine patch image generation. In that where ever the rectangle area is there that part is fixed. Remaining area is scratching.

When you download the images you get different folder images. Please place images in same folder of the android res.(like hdpi,xhdpi,mdpi) and use.

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/thumb8" />
```

Comment: Did you even read my post? Or did you just see that it had to do with 9patch and thought your "answer" would be relevant?  I have 9 patch images.  I haven't been able to locate a good "how-to" on using them in the app.  Where to put them.  What code I need.  Etc.

Comment: Hey i clearly explained where you put. there is folders called drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-mdpi. And generally how you image in the same way use that image.