# Zoomout animation on button press in android

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation

When press a button,i need to animate that button....button will zoom out little on pressed and in orignal size on released..(very much like in tinder)

i use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.9"
    android:toYScale="0.9" >
</scale>
```

but it not work according to my need,,,i need that the button remain small till it is pressed. and become normal on released.

Comment: You need 2 images, one (big) and second (small) and on click you can set small image as its background. Or if you want to show old image on release then use [selector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905937/3531756).

Comment: is there any way to do this using animation..? without using 2 images..

Comment: @GaganDeep - Could you please share your solution?

Comment: @AtulOHolic answer below works for me,try this..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a second animation for returning to unclicked state like this:

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fillAfter="true" 
    android:fromXScale="0.9"
    android:fromYScale="0.9"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" >
</scale>
```

and then :

```
yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          // start your first zoom out Animation here
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         // start zoom in animation which returns to original state
                 break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Dont forget to set fillAfter in your Animations to true, otherwise it will snap back to the original state after the duration has ended.
Or in case you dont want a second animation you can call

```
yourButton.startAnimation(yourAnimation);
```

inside MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
and then call

```
yourButton.clearAnimation();
```

inside MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Comment: it will zoom out only for specific time.. but i need that it will remain small untill  released..

Comment: did you set fillAfter to true?

Comment: why don't we just simply use View#setScaleX and View#setScaleY?