# android ImageView set selector does not worked

Tags: android, android-imageview

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/chiduole_big" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/chiduole"/>
```

this is @drawable/image_selector

xml code

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image_selector"
            />
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? btw do you have this? android:clickable="true"

Comment: when i click the imageview ,it will change its background pic,
add this code android :clickabel="true" is also not worked

Comment: android:background="@drawable/image_selector"  not work too....

Comment: @ErvinZhang, Have you tried googling "android selector"? I'm sure, you must have got a lot of answers. This is one of the reasons why you got downvoted.  Anyways, check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905937/3531756).

Comment: It's better you describe your problem with some more details; and then, readers can get it better and will help you easier and faster :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good. You just should add `android:clickable="true` and `android:focusable="true"` in your ImageView or combine it with your code like `LinearLayout.setClickable(true);`.

And maybe your `image_selector` should look like as follows:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/chiduole_big"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/chiduole_big"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/@drawable/chiduole" />
</selector>
```

### EDIT

I saw what you've done wrong. You've declared `android:onClick="true"`; what goes inside the `onClick` is a method not a boolean. So, you can do something like this:

```
<ImageView android:onClick="MyMethod" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/image_selector" />
```

And then, in Java  you should use the following :

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);

iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyMethod(v);
    }
});

public void MyMethod(View v) {
    // Your Code
}
```

Comment: <ImageView
            android:onClick="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image_selector"
            />

Comment: not worked
log:03-17 19:35:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(11240): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: true [class android.view.View]

Comment: Post your code in your question please, and the Logcat error :)

Answer (score 0):

try putting `android:clickable="true"` in the `ImageView`